# Socket best practices in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server

Writing any kind of web server in Java (be it a webserver, RESTful webapp or a microservice) you get to use Sockets for dual channel communication between client and server.
Using the common `Socket` and `ServerSocket` class is trivial, but since Sockets are blocking, you end up creating a thread for each request. Using this threaded system, your server will work perfectly but won't scale very well.
The alternative is using Streams by means of `SocketChannel`, `ServerSocketChannel` and `Selector`, and is clearly not as trivial as common Sockets.

My question is: which of these two systems are used in production ready code? I'm talking about medium to big projects like Tomcat, Jetty, Sparkjava and the like?
I suppose they all use the Stream approach, right?

Comment: what about websockets?

Comment: @duffy356 what do you mean? Websockets cannot be implemented without NIO but if you think there is some sort of special "WebSocket" as opposed to "ServerSocket" class, you are mistaken.

Answer (score 4):

To make a web server really scalable, you'll have to implement it with [non-blocking I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_%28Java%29) - which means that you should make it in such a way that threads will never get blocked waiting for I/O operations to complete.

Threads are relatively expensive objects. For example, for each thread memory needs to be allocated for its call stack. By default this is in the order of one or a few MB. Which means that if you create 1000 threads, just the call stacks for all those threads will already cost you ~ 1 GB memory.

In a naïve server application, you might create a thread for each accepted connection (each client). This won't scale very well if you have many concurrent users.

I don't know the implementation details of servers like Tomcat and Jetty, but they are most likely implemented using non-blocking I/O.

Some info about non-blocking I/O in Tomcat: [Understanding the Tomcat NIO Connector](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-tomcat-nio)

One of the most well-known non-blocking I/O libraries in Java is [Netty](http://netty.io/).

Comment: Even with blocking IO, production servers use a single thread blocked on the socket. When this thread wakes to accept a connection, it passes it off to a thread in a pool, then returns to blocking. This is the Tomcat BIO connector.

Comment: @BoristheSpider-You mean that Tomcat utilises blocking I/O for its BIO based production system? So, why two different methods -> Tomcat BIO and Tomcat NIO for the production servers! I am slightly confused.. Please explain in brief.

Comment: @BoristheSpider In the Leader-Follower model (non-blocking), a Leader-thread waits on all connections, reads a received request and immediately processes it. Another free Follower-Thread becomes the new Leader, while the old Leader is still processing. Avoids a handoff to another thread.

Comment: The most efficient way is probably non-blocking together with truly asynchronous callbacks. Exactly as many threads as cores handle the connections/callbacks. If any blocking file-IO or remote calls would have to be done, these are instead done by asynchronous callbacks receiving the responses. Very few threads but also very confusing programming even with a framework like akka.

Comment: Some better info about Tomcat [BIO vs. NIO connector](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201201.mbox/%3C4F23E33F.1090700@apache.org%3E). Also, from that email the relation to Servlet 3 Sync vs Async: "If you use an NIO connector that doesn't help you write a chat application more efficiently. You would still need one thread per client. For that you need the Servlet 3.0 Async API. The Async API does not help you efficiently handle many thousands of connections when the majority of them are in HTTP keep-alive. For that you need the NIO connector."

Comment: And it turns out that Netty uses the Streams paradigm.

Comment: The link to the Tomcat NIO Connector article is dead. I wanted to edit the answer but the "suggested edit queue is full". The Tomcat article can now be found here: https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-tomcat-nio